# differentiability of brownian motion

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

for a fixed $t \in [0, \infty)$, I have to show that 
$ \mathbb{P} (D^+W_t = + \infty$ and $D_+W_t = -\infty )$, where $D^+$ (and $D_+$) denotes the upper right-hand derivative (and respectively the lower right-hand derivative ).

I construct a further Brownian motion X by time-inversion of a Brownian motion B, then:

$D^+X(0) \geq \limsup\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{X(1/n)-X(0)}{1/n} \geq \limsup\limits_{n \to \infty} \sqrt n X(1/n) = \limsup\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt n}B(n)$

Now all I need  to prove is that $\limsup\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt n}B(n) = +\infty$ because then I define $X(s) = B(t+s) - B(t)$
 which is a Brownian motion and differentiability of $X$ at $0$ is equivalent to that of $B$ at $t$.

I thought about using Hewitt-Savage $ 0$-$1 $ law to prove the last claim  but I can't conclude.

I think we could also use Borel-cantelli lemma but I don't know how.

If you see another more direct approach I will be glad to take it.

Comment: Since $X(s)=sB(1/s)$, how can you define it as $X(s)=B(t+s)-B(t)$?

Comment: @Error404 I have the exact same question. Do you know an answer now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Tools: Kolmogorov zero-one law, independence of Brownian increments, scaling property of the Brownian paths.

Note that the event $A=[\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}B_n/\sqrt{n}=+\infty]$ is also
$A=[\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}(B_{n+k}-B_k)\sqrt{n}=+\infty],$
for every $k$, hence $A$ is in the tail sigma-algebra of the i.i.d. sequence $(B_n-B_{n-1})$.

Kolmogorov (independent) zero-one law shows that $P[A]$ is $0$ or $1$. By symmetry, $P[A]=P[A']$ where $A'=[\liminf\limits_{n\to\infty}B_n/\sqrt{n}=-\infty]$ hence $A$ is almost sure as soon as $[\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}|B_n|/\sqrt{n}=+\infty]$ is almost sure.

Let $c\gt0$. Note that, if $|x|\leqslant c\sqrt{2^n}$ and $|x+y|\leqslant c\sqrt{2^{n+1}}$ then $|y|\leqslant3c\sqrt{2^n}$. For every $n$, define $A_n=[|B_{2^n}|\leqslant c\sqrt{2^n}]$ then the preceding remark and the independence of the increments of the Brownian motion show that
$$
P[A_{n+1}\mid A_n]\leqslant P[|B_{2^{n+1}}-B_{2^n}|\leqslant3c\sqrt{2^n}]=P[|B_1|\leqslant3c].
$$
The last equal sign uses the Brownian scaling property. Let $p_c$ denote the RHS, thus $p_c\lt1$. For every $k\leqslant\ell$,
$$
P\left[\bigcap_{n=k}^{\ell+1}A_n\right]\leqslant p_cP\left[\bigcap_{n=k}^{\ell}A_n\right],
$$
hence, for every $k$,
$$
P\left[\bigcap_{n\geqslant k}A_n\right]=0,
$$
thus, the event $\liminf\limits_{n\to\infty}A_n$ has probability zero, that is, almost surely, $|B_{2^n}|\gt c\sqrt{2^n}$ for infinitely many $n$, thus,
$$
P[\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}|B_n|/\sqrt{n}\geqslant c]=1.
$$
This holds for every $c$ hence the claim is proved.